# Grouping together micro services internal error codes?

Tags: api, error-handling, refactoring, microservices

Is it a good practice to put all internal error codes and exception class into a common module? or what problems you guys have encounter by doing so...

I am thinking of grouping all these error codes together for re-usability and consistency instead of each micro services having their own error codes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a good idea. It is important that every micro service implements (and documents) its own internal error codes - they are an important part of the service definition. I think it is a bad idea to re-use the same internal error code(s) for different services. Make the documentation part of the service definition (swagger is useful).

It should be easy to understand a service from a client perspective. It should be clean what error codes can be returned for a given service and route. If a client only needs to consume service A - then why force them to use a module that defines error codes for all services?